# Service Layer - Database transactions

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am working on an MVC-EF application that has a Service layer and a Data-access layer. The controllers interact with the service layer and which in turn interacts with the data-access layer. Data-access layer is based on a simplistic implementation of repository pattern exposing the crud operations most of the times.

I am using transactions in my service layer method by doing:

```
bool done = false;
using (IDatabaseTransaction transaction = this.businessDataSource.BeginTransaction())
{
    try
    {
        // Execute some statements updating database
        // ....

        transaction.Commit();

        done = true;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        transaction.Rollback();
    }
}

return done;
```

where BeginTransaction is a method on the repository base class as:

```
    public IDatabaseTransaction BeginTransaction()
    {
        return new DatabaseTransaction(this.Context.Database.BeginTransaction());
    }
```

The implemented service methods in for e.g. EmployeeService, would be like, AddEmployee(Employee emp), AssignEmployeeToDepartments(int empId, IList departmentNames) which have their statements enclosed in a using(IDatabaseTransaction transaction) statements as above, assuming the methods are complex with complex business logic (than it seems from the names :) ).

Now I have to implement a third method for e.g. say ImportEmployee(), which is an aggregate method of previously implemented methods AddEmployee(), and AssignEmployeeToDepartments() implemented earlier. Recalling that the earlier implemented methods are complex and hence need to be reused.

So my question is:

How can I refactor (or implement in a particular way) these service methods, so they can be used individually as well as part of another service method (which also executes its statements in a transaction)?

TIA.

**EDIT:**

I spent some time reading the related posts in stackoverflow and elsewhere and got few ideas how to go about solving the problem. I have described below the one that seems promising.

The key to the solution is "HttpContext.Items" (available through HttpContext.Current.Items), which by definition is a per-request cache. 
Since all my transaction handling is within the service methods, whenever I need to start a new transaction within a service method, I would add a flag in HttpContext.Items by doing:

```
    if (!HttpContext.Current.Items.Contains("HasActiveTranaction"))
        HttpContext.Current.Items.Add("HasActiveTranaction", true);
```

checking that no transaction has already been started. If the key HasActiveTranaction exists, then it would mean this is already being executed as part of another transaction, and in that case not create a transaction. Also, doing the same check before trying to commit or rollback the transaction.

This way it makes it possible to use one service method from another, as well as use both on their own (having their own transactions).

It can be further improved upon by creating a static type TransactionHelper, with a property "HasActiveTranaction" to start with, that centralizes access to it.

Does it sound a good solution?

Comment: Good solution is to have one transaction per request. The implementation depends on your project and you DI container.
Generally you should create your context and begin transaction in Application_Start. Then Application_Error should rollback transaction and you commit in in try-catch block in Application_EndReques. Remember to use same context everywhere. You cant forget about Disposing of DbContext. Is that answer for you?

Comment: I don't think that would be a good idea, because depending upon whether the transaction was Committed or Rolled Back, I have to generate appropriate response/message to the end user giving an indication as to whether the action he was trying, succeeded or failed. Also, in some cases I might also want to perform other actions like send out an appropriate email or log an appropriate contextual message. 
By handling transaction Commit/Rollback in Application_EndRequest, it would be too late to perform any of these actions or generating appropriate response to the end user.

Comment: Investigate TransactionScope. Your sample code above is horribly broken in the error case: The exception is being swallowed. Delete that error handling. Disposing an uncommitted transaction rolls it back.

Comment: Would definitely not recommend one transaction per request.  Usually you want much more explicit control over transactions.

Comment: @usr: The sample code was just to put my point across and it was before I did the "Edit:" to my original question, as it was more of a subsequent and probable idea to solve the problem posted in the original question.

Comment: @Phil: The transaction flag would be reset from the service method where it was started, after Commit() or Rollback(). So it won't really be a single transaction per request.

Comment: I was responding to py3r3str's suggestion--seems like you already ruled out that idea anyway.

Comment: @usr: Even with TransactionScope it would be the same issue as with Transaction, for e.g. if I have a service method Method1() that uses TransactionScope and moving forward if I want to use it from new service method MethodXXX().
And if you are suggesting I use TransactionScope from Controller, I wouldn't prefer to do that as I want the Controllers to be unaware of Db transactions.

Comment: @user3536100 transaction scopes have nice nesting behavior. It's all automatic. Seems to be just what you want.